# Safari 10 overflow + skew bug

Tags: html, css, browser, safari

Stumbled across a visuel bug on Safari 10.1.2 (some versions only somehow). Could you help me find a way through or a workaround to what I want to achieve? It works in all the other tested browsers and on former versions of Safari.

So on Safari 10.1.2 when:

- a positive skewY (bigger than `transform: skewY(0deg);`) is applied to an element
- this element has the property `overflow: hidden;`

the element simply does not display, or only partially. It shows after a ctrl+A "select all."

Here's a JSFiddle to illustrate the problem (note: you need Safari 10 to see what I mean!): https://jsfiddle.net/7c7f4z6v/2/

That is how is displays on every other browser:

[image: safari 10 skew + overflow issue]

And that is how it displays on Safari 10:

[image: safari 10 skew + overflow issue]

Answer (score 0):

This works finde for me in Safari 10.1.2
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help! Here's the real website where I encouter the problem:
— http://unfold.thevolumeproject.com/beta/ Could you tell me if it seems to work for you there a well?

Comment: You're welcome! The website works fine in Safari too, can you provide the exact versions of Safari and your OS? I'll try to reproduce the issue then

Comment: Ah… long story short:
— I don't have Safari 10 myself and the bug was reported last-minute by my client (she uses Safari 10.1.2).
— We also noticed the problem is present on Safari on iOS of the same generation.
— I isolated the problem from an iPhone where I saw the bug since it was the only buggy device I could have access to (that is where the screenshot comes from)
— Since the JSfiddle was bugging in iOS, I expected it to bug on Safari too… but apparently it does not, and the website works as well which contradicts my client!

Still, the website shows problems on Safari on iOS 10.3.3

Comment: She actually saw the issue on http://unfold.thevolumeproject.com/ not on the "beta" version. Could you (oh please :-) confirm me if you see the issue there or not?

Comment: I see, classic last minute issue. The only thing that could cause the problem imo is the overflow: hidden; could you explain what you need it for?

Comment: I didn't, I can provide you a screenshot if needed :-)

Comment: You mean it does not work on http://unfold.thevolumeproject.com but works on http://unfold.thevolumeproject.com/beta/ ?

Comment: Ok thanks a lot! So I wish the issue she saw on her computer came from her own Safari. Nonetheless, the issue I'm describing here is still present on iOS 10.3.3. The fact we noticed the two issues at the same time might just have been misleading.

Comment: I need `overflow: hidden;` when the folder titles are longer than the columns and go on several lines. On the current installement of the website there's no such long titles, but the website is generated from a folder and changes often. Normally the long titles cut at the end of a single line, and an ellipsis "…" is displayed where the text is missing. When hovering with the mouse, the hidden part of the title is revealed.

Comment: I just had a friend showing me on his own Safari 10.1.2 on his new MacBook Pro 15-inch and both the website and the JSfiddle showed the same problem: The yellow paragraph (going down) was not showing up, but after a "select all" (cmd+A) it was… clearly a Safari bug! Unfortunately he had to go so I could not go further in the inquiry.

Comment: Interesting, but I can't think of any reason why a select all would fix that, I'm on an iMac but will take a look at it on my Macbook

Comment: I managed to "fix" the bug by lessening the skewing (which also made pitily my design way more consensual). Under ±10° of skewing Safari still displays the text. It definitely is a Safari glitch, but it would have been nice to find a solution/workaround to keep the design.